# Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, out-of-memory, inflate-exception

I am getting kind of report from user in error report on Google play. I never get this error in my phone galaxy s2 i9100 and other Android phones which I have.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{AnantApps.Moodlytics/anantapps.moodlytics.ui.WhatsNewSlideshow}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
at  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at anantapps.moodlytics.ui.WhatsNewSlideshow.setupSlideShow(WhatsNewSlideshow.java:106)
at anantapps.moodlytics.ui.WhatsNewSlideshow.initViews(WhatsNewSlideshow.java:87)
at anantapps.moodlytics.ui.WhatsNewSlideshow.onCreate(WhatsNewSlideshow.java:55)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:618)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:593)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:445)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:775)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1968)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:109)
... 30 more
```

Some times user report this kind of error also but I failed to reproduce it.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:618)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:593)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:445)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:775)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1968)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:677)
at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:542)
at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:315)
at anantapps.moodlytics.ui.WhatsNewSlideshow.setupSlideShow(WhatsNewSlideshow.java:118)
at anantapps.moodlytics.ui.WhatsNewSlideshow.initViews(WhatsNewSlideshow.java:87)
at anantapps.moodlytics.ui.WhatsNewSlideshow.onCreate(WhatsNewSlideshow.java:55)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

in Activity, My function is like this....

```
private void setupSlideShow(ArrayList<String> titles, ArrayList<String> desc) {

    realViewSwitcher = (HorizontalPager) findViewById(R.id.horizontalPager);
    realViewSwitcher.removeAllViews();

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    for (int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whats_new_slide_show_item, null);
        TextView titleTV = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.whats_new_item_title);
        titleTV.setTypeface(CommonFunctions.getBold(getContext()));
        titleTV.setText(titles.get(i));

        TextView descTV = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.whats_new_item_desc);
        descTV.setTypeface(CommonFunctions.getNormal(getContext()));
        descTV.setText(desc.get(i));

        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_whats_slide);
        img.setImageResource(imgResources.get(i));

        realViewSwitcher.addView(v);

    }

    realViewSwitcher.setOnScreenSwitchListener(onScreenSwitchListener);

}
```

whats_new_slide_show_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/whats_new_item_title"
                    style="@style/whats_new_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Large Text" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_whats_slide"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/bug_fixes" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/whats_new_item_desc"
                    style="@style/whats_new_desc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Medium Text" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

whats_new_slide_show.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/whats_new_slides_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bar_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/whats_new_header"
        style="@style/TopBarTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/whats_new_title" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/seperator_whats_new" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next_slide"
        style="@style/Whats_new_btn"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/whats_new_next_btn"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_next" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/whats_new_slides_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/tra_white_ninety" >

    <anantapps.moodlytics.view.HorizontalPager
        android:id="@+id/horizontalPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </anantapps.moodlytics.view.HorizontalPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to pre-load all your images for your slideshow.  If you redesign your app to only load images when they are viewed, it will have much less peak memory usage which will help you avoid out-of-memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into the out of memmory error so i will try to tell about that.

Things you should try:

1) Clear resourses (`System.gc();` and `Runtime.getRuntime().gc();`) on pause or on destroy on previous activity.

2) (Which was my problem) Make sure that your images are big as the bigest screen your app is running on or suporting.(I had two design elements with resolution 1000x486 and it gave me out of memmory error).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.but System.gc() does not clear resources my friend :)

Comment: Ok i frogot that it tells to run `Garbage collector`